# Observable.Timer or TPL with Task.Delay

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I have a requirement where after an initial delay of 10 seconds, I need to execute `SomeMethod` at every 10 minutes, but with a catch that 10 minute timer should start after the completion of `SomeMethod`. Here is the crude example:

```
Start Task 00:00:00
(10 second delay)
SomeMethod executed at 00:00:10 (takes 15 minutes)
(10 minute delay)
SomeMethod executed at 00:25:10 
... and so on.
```

I know how to do this using TPL. I can start the task using Task.Delay and execute `SomeMethod` and then after every completion (`ContinueWith TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`), I create a new task and execute `SomeMethod` again.

My question is that is this possible using `Observable.Timer`? Something like...

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
```

The problem with this code is that if `SomeMethod` takes 15 minutes, I will have two different `SomeMethod` instances running, which I don't want. I want the 10 minute timer to start **after** `SomeMethod` completes. Is this possible using `Observable` or should I stay with TPL?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that I want `SomeMethod` to run in it's own thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have done some more investigation into using `Observable.Timer`. It works almost like you want straight out of the box.

One important thing to understand about Rx is that it guarantees that you will never get concurrent executions of a single subscription. While Rx might enable all sorts of multi-threading scenarios it will always serialize subscriptions.

So, take this observable subscription as an example:

```
Observable
    .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    .Timestamp()
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    });
```

I've created an observable that will wait 10 seconds to begin emitting values and will then **try** to emit a value every 2 seconds.

I've then added `.Timestamp()` to record exactly when the values are produced.

Finally, I've subscribed with an observer that forces a 5 second thread sleep.

Here's the first 4 values output:

```
0@2015-08-31 10:44:34 +00:00
1@2015-08-31 10:44:39 +00:00
2@2015-08-31 10:44:44 +00:00
3@2015-08-31 10:44:49 +00:00
```

You'll notice that the gap between the values is 5 seconds. This is pretty close to what you want. Rx sees that the two seconds has elapsed and executes the next value immediately.

But there is another Rx operator that does exactly what you want - `.Generate(...)`. This is a very powerful operator for generating all sorts of observable streams.

You want to use it like this:

```
Observable
    .Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1, x => x,
        x => x == 0 ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0) : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    .Timestamp()
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    });
```

In this case it works exactly the way you want. Here's the first ten values:

```
0@2015-08-31 10:48:27 +00:00
1@2015-08-31 10:48:34 +00:00
2@2015-08-31 10:48:41 +00:00
3@2015-08-31 10:48:48 +00:00
4@2015-08-31 10:48:55 +00:00
5@2015-08-31 10:49:02 +00:00
6@2015-08-31 10:49:09 +00:00
7@2015-08-31 10:49:16 +00:00
8@2015-08-31 10:49:23 +00:00
9@2015-08-31 10:49:30 +00:00
```

It's firing every 7 seconds. The 2 from the generate operator and the 5 from the observer.

You can obviously put in the times you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was doing the exact same thing but was not getting the result as I missed an important detail in my question. I want to run SomeMethod in its own seperate thread with the expected behaviour. I guess it involves SubscribeOn (or ObserveOn?), but I get really confused with it. I have a very basic knowledge of Rx.

Comment: @Yogesh - you probably should use a new instance of `EventLoopScheduler` in `ObserveOn` or add  directly in `.Generate(...)`.

Comment: Your `Generate` solution works perfectly with `SubscribeOn` (`Timer` doesn't). I also read into the `LongRunningTask` issue with using `TaskPoolScheduler.Default`, but it seems to affect `ObserveOn` more because it tries to create a thread for every observe. Although I am still profiling, I think the solution should work without any OOM exceptions. If it does seem to create memory related issues, I still have `TaskPoolScheduler.Default.DisableOptimizations(typeof(ISchedulerLongRunning))`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `SomeMethod` emits an `OnCompleted` event when it completes, we can write it as an `Observable`

```
//If SomeMethod OnCompleted conforms to .NET Event Pattern
var completedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<OnCompletedEventArgs>(
            e => this.OnCompleted += e,
            e => this.OnCompleted += e);

//Subscribe to OnCompleted events
var repeatDisposable = completedObservable.Subscribe(_ => 
                                Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
                                          .Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod()));

//Start condition
var starterDisposable = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                                  .Subscribe(_ => SomeMethod());
```

Comment: I meant `ContinueWith TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` instead of `ContinueWith OnCompleted`. Fixed in question. The method does not implement any completion event. It is a nice solution though. Upvoted.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to start polluting methods with Completed events. I would also be wary of using Subscribe within a Subscribe, partly due to disposable-related issues, and partly because your Subscribe should be there to process the output of a steam rather than kicking off new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Chris , do you have a suggestion on how to improve the subscription ?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to string together observables, then using a SelectMany to create 1 pipeline is the best approach. You can then have a single subscribe block which consumes this pipeline. This isn't going to look pretty in a comment but something like this: (from result1 in Obs1() from result2 in Obs2() select result2).Subscribe(x => {...}, ex => {...})